# Self Program Third (Spare) 2009 Honda Odyssey EX

Tags: honda, key, ignition-key

I have a 2009 Honda Odyssey with two existing ignition keys. They are both transponder (chip) keys. I would like to purchase a third spare transponder key, have it cut, and self program it. Many makes allow you to self program a third key.

Is it possible to self program a third transponder key for a 2009 Honda Odyssey? If so, how would you do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, the Honda Odyssey(european Shuttle) requires diagnsotic equipment to programme keys.